Why is Kubernetes' pod CPU and memory load uneven?
I'm running a Kubernetes Deployment with four Pods. Each Pod is expected to share the load equally, but I've noticed that one Pod consistently uses significantly more CPU and memory than the others. I suspect this issue might be related to kube-proxy's iptables mode, but I'm not sure of the exact cause.
[root@iac ~]# kubectl top pod --sort-by=memory | grep api
api-5cd64b46cb-b9ffs                        183m         1220Mi   
api-5cd64b46cb-4m8h6                        172m         952Mi      
api-5cd64b46cb-hrnhw                        168m         939Mi           
api-5cd64b46cb-kbm7d                        215m         895Mi

I’ve checked the resource limits and requests for the pods, and they’re all configured identically.

so, look inside the pods and figure out what they're doing differently.

Nobody can answer that with the provided info. As least you must tell how the load is generated. Via a service I guess since "kube-proxy" is mentioned. But how does the service look like? Is traffic internal, or from an external source, etc?
